# if image loaded jquery then run cycle

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.previewnetcoid').html('<img src="/www-static/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: block; margin: 170px auto;">');
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.previewnetcoid').show();
        $('.previewnetcoid').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollLeft', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            speed:    2000,
            timeout:  6000
        });
    });
});
```

as you can see, **im trying to do give a loader then when if all of my image loaded it will show the images**. i think i get it wrong here. it only shows the loader

edit* my progress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.previewnetcoid').hide();
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#ajax-loader').hide();
        $('.previewnetcoid').show();
        $('.previewnetcoid').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollLeft', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            speed:    2000,
            timeout:  6000
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: What was in `$('.previewnetcoid')` before the `.html(...)` call? The `.html(...)` call will replace any existing elements with the loader image.

Comment: some div contents with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replaced the content of the element represented by `.previewnetcoid` with the loader, so the original content is gone. Thus, there's nothing to cycle.

Also, this isn't even done until the page has already been completely loaded (`$(document).ready()`), so you're effectively waiting until the page is completely rendered to show a loading animation. That's obviously not right.

You should place the loading animation HTML in the actual document, and use CSS to make it cover and hide the page (positioned absolutely, with 100% width and height, and a background). Then, in your javascript have it hidden on page load.

Alternatively, you should probably write the loading HTML with JavaScript:

```
<script>document.write(...)</script>
```

Otherwise, if a user has JavaScript disabled, they'll get the loading image, but it will never be removed.

**EDIT:** (providing example)

CSS

```
.loading {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:#000;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="loading.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<div class="loading"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    </script>
    ...
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.loading').hide();
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that both the CSS and the HTML for the loader should be among the first things in the document. Preferably, stylesheet should be in the `<head>` and the loading HTML should be the first thing after `<body>`. That way, it will be already fully rendered before the rest of the page loads.

Comment: @Adam when you use `.html(...)` to set an element's inner HTML, that will completely obliterate/blow away/remove/destroy/replace/wipe out what was there before.